# Change of a form of a pagination

Tags: php, sql

Could you help me change my pagination code?

Perfect that it would look like:

< PREVIOUS 1 2 3 4 5 NEXT>

I am grateful to everyone in advance for the time I have devoted to my problem. Thanks.

My code:

```
<?php } else echo 'Ничего не найдено!';
//вывод страниц-ссылок для переходов, если результатов больше 10, 
if($pages) {
    for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++) { ?>
    <a href="<?echo $url.'&page='.$i;?>">[<?=$i?>]</a>
    <?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution:

```
<? if (isset($pages) && $pages > 1) : ?>
    <? $left_pages = 4; $right_pages = 4; ?>
    <? $_GET['page'] = (int)@$_GET['page']; ?>
    <? $_GET['page'] = $_GET['page'] < 1 ? 1 : $_GET['page']; ?>
    <? $_GET['page'] = $_GET['page'] > $pages ? $pages : $_GET['page']; ?>

    <? $left = $_GET['page'] - $left_pages; ?>
    <? $right = $_GET['page'] + $right_pages; ?>
    <? if ($left <= 0) {$right += (-1)*$left; $left = 1;} ?>
    <? if ($right > $pages) $right = $pages; ?>
    <? $pages_range = range($left, $right); ?>

    <ul class="pagination">
        <? if ($left > 1) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $url.'&page=1' ?>">1</a></li>
        <? endif; ?>

        <? if ($_GET['page'] > 1) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $url.'&page='.($_GET['page']-1) ?>">&lt; PREV</a></li>
        <? endif; ?>

        <? foreach($pages_range as $page) : ?>
            <? $class = ''; if ($_GET['page'] === $page) $class = 'current'; ?>
            <li class="<?= $class ?>"><a href="<?= $url.'&page='.$page?>"><?= $page ?></a></li>
        <? endforeach; ?>

        <? if ($_GET['page'] < $pages) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $url.'&page='.($_GET['page']+1) ?>">NEXT &gt;</a></li>
        <? endif; ?>

        <? if ($right < $pages) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $url.'&page='.$pages ?>"><?= $pages ?></a></li>
        <? endif; ?>

        <? if ($pages > 20) : ?>
        <li>
            <form method="get">
                or jump to page: <input type="text" name="page" size="3" value="<?= $_GET['page'] ?>" maxlength="<?= strlen($pages) ?>">
                <button>ok</button>
            </form>
        </li>
        <? endif; ?>
    </ul>
<? endif; ?>
```

```css
<style>
    ul.pagination {
      list-style: none;
    }

    ul.pagination>li {
      float: left;
      padding: 4px;
      margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
      border: 0;
    }
    ul.pagination>li>a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #03adfc;
    }
    ul.pagination>li>a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    ul.pagination>li.current>a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    ul.pagination>li.current>a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

Example link: http://anarjafarov.me/pagination.php?&page=30

```css
ul.pagination {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.pagination>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
  border: 0;
}
ul.pagination>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #03adfc;
}
ul.pagination>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul.pagination>li.current>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
ul.pagination>li.current>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?&page=1">1</a></li>

    <li><a href="?&page=49">&lt; PREV</a></li>

    <li class=""><a href="?&page=46">46</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="?&page=47">47</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="?&page=48">48</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="?&page=49">49</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="?&page=50">50</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="?&page=51">51</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="?&page=52">52</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="?&page=53">53</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="?&page=54">54</a></li>

    <li><a href="?&page=51">NEXT &gt;</a></li>

    <li><a href="?&page=200">200</a></li>

    <li>
        <form method="get">
            or jump to page: <input type="text" name="page" size="3" value="50" maxlength="3">
            <button>ok</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
Your code works! I am very glad!

Can I ask you another question?

How do I limit the code as this?

PREV ... 192 193 194 195 196... NEXT

Comment: The code now looks like this:

PREV 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 NEXT

Comment: @VladimirEIS ok, I’ll write soon

Comment: @VladimirEIS updated my answer, and check this: http://anarjafarov.me/pagination.php?page=50

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything perfectly works!